# Play framework - Content Security Policy setting doesn't work?

Tags: playframework

I use sbt to build a play-scala-seed project, and add a simple:

```
<button id="doclick" onclick="doConsole();">click</button>
```

But when I start the project and click the button. Console gives the error output:

> localhost/:17 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

application.conf

```
play.http.filters = "filter.Filters"
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
```

Just follow the offical doc [play-securityheaders](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SecurityHeaders)

Did I miss something or get the wrong path cause still can not call inline script?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found the solution after 2 hours of fiddling with it.

I am using compile-time dependency injection and I changed the application mixin from `HttpFiltersComponents` to `NoHttpFiltersComponents`, which solved the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that this disables all security headers. You can disable the CSP header in particular by adding `play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = null` to `application.conf`. But that's also a bad idea.